# Can't add new command when connection is in closed state (express.js + mysql2 + mysql2/promise + clearDB + heruko)

Tags: mysql, express, mysql2, cleardb, heroku-addon

**i am facing thi error whenever i make a second call to the api i created using mysql2+expressjs+clearDB(on HERUKO)+heruko deployment server**

> this is my code ....

```
const [rows,fields]= await db.execute(MYQUERY,[myarguments])
```

> i am calling the mysql server like this with asyn/await functionality which mysql2 provides

```
import mysql from 'mysql2/promise'
```

> after that i create the the connection

```
 let db = await mysql.createconnection({
 host: 'localhost',
 user: "root",
 password: "asdzxcasdzxc123123",
 database: "doctorapp"
```

})
export { db }

> Any sollution to this error...???

Answer (score 1):

i was facing this error in **mysql2/promise**

> **Reason for this error**

The actual problem is with **mysql2/promise** .

when you create your connection with **mysql database** with **mysql2 npm package**
this thing is causing the error...

> **Sollution to this error**

i solved this error by creating my connection with mysql.creatPool(yourCredentials)

> **creat your db config file like this**

```
import mysql from 'mysql2'

let db = mysql.createPool({
host: 'Enter your host here',
user: "enter user name here",
password: "enter you password",
database: "enter the database name",
waitForConnections: true,
connectionLimit: 10,
queueLimit: 0
})
export { db }
```

> **Use of db in your contollers or router should be like this**

```
 const promise = db.promise()
 const select_user_query=`
 select *
 from users
 `
 const [rows,fields]= await promise.execute(select_user_query)
 return res.status(200).json({users:rows})
```

> **One thing to note===>**

you have to create

```
const promise= db.promise()
```

in all the contollers ... so it will automatically handles all the required **connnection release** or other things required to make the connection working perfectly